# Creating models in typescript that take injectables

Tags: typescript, angular

I am creating a user model in typescript, with the following:

```
import {Inject} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from "angular2/http";

export class User {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    constructor(User:User, @Inject(Http) private _http){
        this.firstName = User.firstName;
        this.lastName = User.lastName;
    }
    getUserFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    addUser(){
        return this._http.post('/api/user/',this);
    }
}
```

And in other places,I use:

```
var use = new User(userObject) // where userObject is an object with firstName and lastName
```

And this creates object, with two methods: `getUsername` and  `addUser`.

However, there is an issue with injecting the `http`. It is always undefined. Do you have any pointers or solutions to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want parameters injected to a class, you need to delegate instantiating to the injector. If you create an instance yourself with `new SomeClass()` no injection will take place.

If you want a single instance you can just add the type to the providers and inject it.

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, HTTP_PROVIDERS, User]);
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private user:User);
}
```

If you want multiple instances (Angular DI creates singletons by default and always returns the same instance) you can use a factory.

```
@Injectable()
export class User {
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
    constructor(User:User, @Inject(Http) private _http){
        this.firstName = User.firstName;
        this.lastName = User.lastName;
    }
    getUserFirstName(){
        return this.firstName;
    }

    addUser(){
        return this._http.post('/api/user/',this);
    }
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [OtherProviders, HTTP_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(User, {useFactory: 
        () => return (http) => new User(http);}, 
        deps: [Http])]);
```

```
export class MyComponent {
  consturctor(@Inject(User) private userFactory) {
    user = this.userFactory();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make injectable a class you need a decorator around it, the `@Injectable` one. But in this case, Angular2 will instantiate the class by it own and provide it within the constructor of the class where you want to use it.

If you want to instantiate the class by yourself, you need to provide the dependency (in a service or in a component):

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
}

otherMethod() {
  var use = new User(userObject, this.http);
}
```

You can remove the `@Inject` decorator in this case from the `User` class.

Comment: I was thinking about that way to do this - but I thought it was not really 'clean' way. But thanks! I will mark this as answer unless someone proposes something else shortly

Comment: Yes I still believe this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: IMHO there is nothing wrong with this approach if you want to create (`User`) instances imperatively.

Comment: Yes agreed. Nothing wrong with this approach. But this can be more better else no problem with this approach as well..